# Fortran 90 - How to create a coordinate system

Tags: array, fortran

So I need to code a simple program, and I need to define 2D coordinates?

Is there any coordinate system I can use in Fortran?

I was told it might have to be all in arrays? And if so, can anybody push me in the right direction as to how to set up 2d arrays?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: I don't know where to start, to be honest. Thanks

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: In addition, if you do not know where to start, ploughing through some introductory material helps (e.g. online tutorials). Once you have more Fortran context, you might either solve your problem, or know what to ask for.

Comment: Hint: 2D coordinates are just a pair of numbers. Fortran per se does not have a notion of coordinate system, but I suppose any geometry libraries might like to use do. Consult their documentation. If you don't plan to use such libraries, just do the natural thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 2D array. Googling for `fortran 2d array` led me to: [How to initialize two-dimensional arrays in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708307/how-to-initialize-two-dimensional-arrays-in-fortran)

Which includes:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(3, 3) :: array
array = reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /), shape(array))
```

which you can easily change to your situation.

Alternatively, you can create a custom `coordinate` type, and fill an array with those custom types. See for example: [Array of derived type: select entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847117/array-of-derived-type-select-entry)

which includes:

```
type Element
    logical active
    integer type
    real width
    ! etc
end type

type(Element), allocatable :: elements(:)
```

Which, if adapted to your situation, would provide a nice way to having an allocatable array of 2D coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Although mathematically you need 2D concept to deal with points in a 2D space, you can use 1D arrays in your Fortran code to accomplish your task. For instance, if you have 100 points in a 2D plane to work with, you can define two 1D arrays x and y as follows:

```
real:: x(100), y(100)
```

and then you can treat x(i) and y(i) as a pair representing the *i*th point, and perform whatever calculation you want.